# Not returning first match in a piped regex

Tags: python, regex

```
txt = 'Teena is Positive. Sara is Negative'
reg = re.compile(r'(Teena|Sara).*(Positive|Negative)')
result = re.search(reg, txt).group(1)
print(result)
```

This returns 'Negative' while I expected 'Positive'. I assumed that the first match is returned. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Use [`r'(Teena|Sara).*?(Positive|Negative)'`](https://regex101.com/r/xBV8i4/2). `.group(2)` will return `Positive` then.

Comment: For me, it returns `'Teena'`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise that this was asked earlier. Apologies. You saved my day.